# MongoDB: Is it possible to specify a secondary index and view the execution plan with an update command?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using MongoDB running on Ubuntu.

I'm aware it's not possible to use .hint() or .explain() methods in conjunction with an update command to:

1) specify an Index to be used in the query part of the command, and 
2) verify the execution plan

Are there alternatives available to .hint() and 'explain() that can be used with update? I want to update a single record and force Mongo to use the Secondary index rather than the primary.

Grateful for any suggestions,
Jon

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to use `$hint` or an alternative for an update. There is an open JIRA ticket for this, which you can see [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599). It says that it's "planned but not scheduled" and it has a bunch of votes, so it might be implemented in one of MongoDB's future releases.

Comment: Juan - many, many thanks for commenting and advising of this. I've been round in circles trying to solve this one. Regards,

Comment: Not a problem! I will add an extended version of my comment as an answer.

Comment: Jon, may I ask why you want to specify a specific index?

Comment: Of course - I'm using MongoDB for the first time (as part of a Masters Degree I'm studying) and I'm running a series of tests against Mongo and other Dbs to compare performance. Having tested performance by updating records utilising the primary index, the next logical tests were to attempt to test using NoIndex and Secondary Indexes.

Comment: Ah I see. If that's the case then I guess you can just say that that feature is not currently supported in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in one of my comments to the question, as of MongoDB version 2.6.3 there is no alternative to `$hint` for an update. However, it does seem to be planned for future releases, as there is an [open JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599) for that feature with the status "planned but not scheduled".

It is a similar story for `$explain`. However, it does appear that this feature will be coming soon. There is a JIRA task for revamping `explain()` and one of its subtasks is entitled "[Explain Command for Explaining Update and findAndModify](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14101)". The value for the "Fix Version" field is "2.7 Required".